# Openlayers: How to highlight a point on mouse over a line

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap, javascript

Any suggestions on how to highlight a point on mouse over a line, I've read points from a javascript array, lines are drawn by using them and I want to highlight some points in that array by moving the mouse pointer through the line and near to that point. However, i'm  stuck on actually how to get started with this.
[image: This image contains the lines:]

Any guidance and help is appreciated..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time of line creation, I would loop through the vertices of the line, cloning the vertices and creating points out of them. Then I would style the point features to respond to your highlighting.

This should make it a lot easier.

## Update per comment:

[Here is a working demo.](http://users8.jabry.com/captdragon/ol/highlightVertices.htm)

[image]

The key here is creating point features from the line vertices:

```js
var arrPoints = lineFeature.geometry.getVertices();
var arrPointFeatures = [];
for (var x in arrPoints) {
    arrPointFeatures.push(new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(arrPoints[x].clone()));
}
pointLayer.addFeatures(arrPointFeatures);
```

## Update #2 per comment:

If you don't want the default points to be seen initially, define the default render intent and set `strokeColor: 'Transparent'` & `fillColor: 'Transparent'`. You cannot use `display:'none'` because the point will not render.

[Here is the **NEW DEMO**](http://users8.jabry.com/captdragon/ol/highlightVertices2.htm)

[image]

```js
var pointLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Points", {
    styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
        "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
            strokeColor: 'Transparent',
            fillColor: 'Transparent',
            pointRadius: 6
        }),
        "temporary": new OpenLayers.Style({
            strokeColor: '#0000cc',
            fillColor: '#0000cc',
            strokeOpacity: .8,
            strokeWidth: 1,
            fillOpacity: .3,
            cursor: "default",
            pointRadius: 6
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: can you please give some example, so that i can refer it.

Comment: @bios Please see my update.

Comment: Is it possible to hide all these points and show that only mouse over it.

Comment: @bios Please see my Update #2.

Answer (score 4):

use OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature with hover:

```
        var make_hover= function(e) {
            console.log(e.feature.id);
            vector.features[x].style.fillColor = "#00b4ff"; //Your Point
            vectorLayer.redraw();
        };

        var highlightCtrl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vectorLayer, {
            hover: true,
            highlightOnly: true,               
            eventListeners: {
                beforefeaturehighlighted: another_Function,
                featurehighlighted: make_hover,
                featureunhighlighted: another_Function
            }
        });
```

i hope it helps you....

Comment: Is there anyway to add different colors on start and end coordinates in a kml

Comment: or is it possible to display kml coordinates as a point feature along with the actual kml path

Comment: check out this - openlayers kml with external styles [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461437/openlayers-kml-with-external-styles)